# custom observer enable/disable dependent on store config value - magento 2

Tags: magento2, observers

have a custom module with a custom observer. i also added a `disable/enable` option for this functionality to a store config value for admin backend.

is there a way of completely disabling the observer if the store config value is disabled thorugh a `xml` file for example? right now i only have an if statment after the execute function of the observer so the functions inside the observer are not executed when the backend config is set to `disabled`.
i guess it would be more elegant to disable the observer completely if the config value in backend is set to `disabled`?

i hope this makes sense. thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the way you mentioned is the only way to disable an observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if($disabled) {return;}
    //your code here
}
```